# How to Display Column Data in Input Once Different Column Data Has Been Selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form with a select field and an input field:

[image]

The select field takes all of the customer names from the customer table's customer_name column, and allows the user to choose a customer name. Once a customer's name has been chosen, it will take that name and display it in the "Add Customer Name" input, and take the customers phone number (from the phone_num column in the customer table) and display it in the "Customer Phone" input.

I am using My_SQL and PHP to do this.

So far, I can correctly display the customer names in the "Customer" select field. But, the name does not appear in the "Add Customer Name" input nor does it display the customer's phone number in the "Customer Phone" input.

Does anyone know how to do this using PHP, JavaScript, or perhaps a mix of both?

Here is the code from this part of the web form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#customer").change(function() {
            if($( "#customer option:selected" ).text() == 'Add a Customer') {
                    $( "#customer_name" ).show();
                    $( "#cusphone" ).show();
                    $( "#cusphone1" ).show();
                    $( "#customer_name1" ).show();
            } else {
                $( "#customer_name" ).hide();
                $( "#cusphone" ).hide();
                $( "#cusphone1" ).hide();
                $( "#customer_name1" ).hide();
            }
        });
});

</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_invoice.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="travel_task" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Customer<span class="brand-color"></span>:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select id="customer" name="customer" required class="chosen-select-deselect form-control" width="380">
              <option value=''></option>
                  <?php
                    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT distinct(customer_name) FROM customer");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        if ($customer_name == $row['customer_name']) {
                            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                        } else {
                            $selected = '';
                        }

                        echo "<option ".$selected." value = '".$row['customer_name']."'>".$row['customer_name']."</option>";
                            }
                  ?>
                  <option value = 'Other'>Add a Customer</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="travel_task" id="customer_name" style="display: none;" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Add Customer Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input name="customer_name" id="customer_name1" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: none;"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="site_name" id="cusphone1" style="display: none;" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input name="cusphone" id="cusphone" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: none;"/>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: You do have a closing `</form>` tag, right? It's not in your code.

Comment: Yes, this is just a piece from the form, the form has about 8 other input fields.

Comment: Where are you defining `$customer_name`? As per `if ($customer_name == $row['customer_name'])` it's just a stray variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, allow me to sum up my inquiry. Basically all I need is PHP to take the value of one input after it has been entered in by the user (and before hitting submit). For example, a user types in the word "Joe", and before hitting submit, PHP will take the value, and search for "Joe" in the Customers table's customer_name column. Is there anyway to do this?